# PHPMailer Gmail SMTP Contact Us Form AddReplyTo

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I have the following code. As you can see im setting the replyTo field to the email inputted inside the contact us form. However this does not work. Everytime i receive an email from my contact form, I then need to copy the email (which is in my message body) and paste it into the "to" field. Since the to field will ignore the fact i placed a different replyto email and simply use my websites email. Any idea what could be wrong?

```
require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "email";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "password";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom("mywebsitesemail", "my name");
$mail->AddAddress("mywebsitesemail", "my name");
$mail->AddReplyTo("$email","$name");

$mail->Subject    = "Subject";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML("$message");



$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Try adding `$mail->From = "$email";` to the code

Comment: `$mail->From` Gets set when calling setFrom along with `$mail->FromName`

Comment: this is my question too. but i found answer. go here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336402/phpmailer-gmail-smtp-not-working-properly/