# PHPMailer - gmail smtp not working properly

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I use **gmail smtp** for **contact form** in my site.(PHPMailer script https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer‎)
my code is:

```
<?php
include "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "main@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
$mail->SetFrom("another@gmail.com");
$mail->addReplyTo("another@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Your Gmail SMTP Mail";
$mail->Body = "Hi, your first SMTP mail via gmail server has been received.";
$mail->AddAddress("main@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send()){
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

It works but i have two problems:

1. I set `$mail->SetFrom("another@gmail.com");`
    but in my gmail show `from: main@gmail.com`
2. I set `$mail->addReplyTo("another@gmail.com");` 
   but in my gmail when i click replay button email replayed to `main@gmail.com`

   my code is

Comment: Why are you using "main" in the script `$mail->Username = "main@gmail.com";`?

Comment: this is email that emails must send to it from my site(this is not real email that i use just for example) `$mail->Username = "main@gmail.com";` is username to conect gmail smtp.`another@gmail.com` is an email that user enter in contact form

Comment: Does "main@gmail.com" belong to you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my answer.
in your Gmail go to

```
setting ->accounts ->Send mail as
```

*click Add another email address you own*
in new window enter new email address (example if your gmail is `yourmail@gmail.com` you must enter `your.mail@gmail.com`)or(if your gmail address have dot you must change position of dot.
example if your gmail is `yo.urmail@gmail.com` you must enter `yourma.il@gmail.com`)
don't forget uncheck **Treat as an alias**.
click next step.
[image]

go back to `setting ->accounts ->Send mail as`
make a new email as defult
check `Reply from the same address the message was sent to`

all done!
i change code use new codes.
[image]

now show from my site

[image]

now when you click replay botton show replay to user email
[image]

```
<?php
include "classes/class.phpmailer.php"; // include the class name
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "yourmail@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxxx";
$mail->addReplyTo("useremail@gmail.com","user");
$mail->SetFrom("useremail@gmail.com","My Site");
$mail->Subject = "Your Gmail SMTP Mail";
$mail->Body = "Hi, your first SMTP mail via gmail server has been received.";
$mail->AddAddress("yourmail@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send()){
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
    echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

Comment: i confirm this works great, but can't upvote because i don't have enough reputation to use the system like i should.

Answer (score 5):

Google does not allow you to send mail on behalf of another user [aka "spoof"] unless you've explicitly been allowed. If you have not been allowed it will rewrite the address to the address of the sending account.

To add an account log into gmail, and go to Settings > Accounts > Send Mail As... when you add an address here gmail will send a message to that address asking for confirmation to allow you to send mail on their behalf.

Comment: I have many visitors that use contact form with various emails

Comment: @user2511140 well, you can either convince Gmail to stop doing email correctly, stop spoofing other peoples' email addresses, or use another SMTP provider.

Answer (score -3):

It is simpler to put anchor with mailto in 
end of email text, eg:

```
<h4><a href="mailto:some@one.com"> Click to answer </a> </h4>
```

When user clicks on this anchor, pop-up will open with correct email address
in send field.