# Remove previous message header when reply, using PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer to create Contact form. It is working fine. But When I reply to received message, user is receiving my reply include with previous data.

owner_address@gmail.com = admin Email Address.
User Name = Email sender from Contact Form.

```
On Wed, Jul 30, 2014 at 1:35 AM, User Name<owner_address@gmail.com> wrote:

First Email Data
```

It is showing user name correctly, but it is showing my email address (not the user's email)
I want to remove email address or change it to user address.

Below is my code;

```
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['your_name']))
{
return false;
}
$name = $_POST['your_name'];
$email = $_POST['your_email'];
$subject = $_POST['your_subject'];
$msg = $_POST['description'];


include "PHPMailerAutoload.php"; // include the class name
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "owner_address@gmail.com"; 
$mail->Password = "owner_password";
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom($email, $name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $msg;
$mail->AddAddress("owner_address@gmail.com");
if(!$mail->Send()){
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else{
echo "OK";
}
?>
```

Thank you,
Sameera Silva

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396264/phpmailer-reply-using-only-reply-to-address

Comment: I have tried it already. It didn't work for me.

Comment: gmail doesn't let you send from other addresses (unless they are handling mail for your domain), so it will be changing the address as you send.

Comment: But I used [This Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336402/phpmailer-gmail-smtp-not-working-properly/)
So it is working perfect and when I click reply on received mail, it is correctly showing Contact form senders email. But when I send reply to contact form user, it shows below details. I just wanna remove it or edit it.

`On Wed, Jul 30, 2014 at 1:35 AM, User Name<owner_address@gmail.com> wrote:

First Email Data`